# Input decimal or double numbers in JAVA

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How can I input a decimal or double number as it is? I want if I input .56 it saves in the database as .56 not 1 because its rounding up and I want to ignore the rounding...

This is servlet, well I have beans and its also set to double; I also tried DecimalFormat but still not working or maybe I just don't know how to use it.

```
neutrophils = rs.getInt("neutrophils");
monocytes = rs.getInt("monocytes");
eosinophils = rs.getInt("eosinophils");
basophils = rs.getInt("basophils");
lymphocytes = rs.getInt("lymphocytes");

total= (neutrophils + monocytes + eosinophils + eosinophils + basophils + lymphocytes);
```

---

I made it like this, I changed the value of datatype to VARCHAR but the error is java.lang.NullPointerException; why is that?

```
neutrophils = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("neutrophils"));
monocytes = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("monocytes"));
eosinophils = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("eosinophils"));
basophils = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("basophils"));
lymphocytes = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("lymphocytes"));
bands = (neutrophils + monocytes + eosinophils + eosinophils + basophils + lymphocytes);
```

Comment: rs.getString and then change it to double

Comment: Am I missing something? Why not just use `rs.getFloat` or `rs.getDouble`? We are talking about `ResultSet`, right? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Comment: yeah result set... Does my database affects the result in the jsp page? because it's the datatype is INT so i'm planning to make it VARCHAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `rs` is `ResultSet` you can simply use `rs.getDouble`. If for some reason you don't want to use it, get the result as a String and then convert

```
Double.parseDouble(rs.getString(ColumnLabel));
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException... why is that?